# making "Untraceable"-like calls

Tags: modem, call

In the movie [Untraceable](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0880578/), the killer (Joseph Cross as KillWithMe.com's webmaster) makes a telephone call with a computer and using some software(that convert's the actor's voice to female) fakes himself as a girl.

While the *converting* part may be technologically difficult to accomplish at this time, I wanted to ask whether it is possible to make calls with a computer, record the conversations and play an mp3 file so the other person hears it? How can this be done?

Comment: I want to use a landline to do this and someone mentioned in one of the above posts about Audacity- could someone pls elaborate on that.

Comment: If you call with a land line then your killing career probably won't last too long.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a voice changer check this out http://skypefx.codeplex.com/ or just google Skype voice changer.

If you want to make your calls very hard to trace then:

Get a private VPN service then make a fake email account, setup a Skype account and buy a Skype card with cash from somewhere (Target, WalMart etc..). I'd say that's untracable enough.

The person you call can see the Skype number and report it to the police and if you did something that would be a felony like a bomb threat or something. They would subpoena Skype with the time of the call and the number. Skype would respond with the incoming IP address of the call then the police would have to go to the ISP (the VPN provider in this case) and ask who had that IP address at that time. The VPN provider will probably say "I don't know" since they're not **supposed** to keep logs, but sometimes they do and they may respond with you IP address. Then the police would have to subpoena the ISP and find out who had that IP address at that time to get your address. Then they would have to get a warrant for your arrest and get it to your local PD who would have to be willing to go arrest you and the investigating PD would have to be willing to pay to have you extradited, which they probably will only do if you have done something bad enough that you won't be able to post bail.

Now that's just my take on it, this isn't legal advice and I'm sure they want you bad enough they will find you. If you're just going to do some prank calls that should be good enough.

Comment: Holy crap my grammar was horrible. Thanks Heptite!

Answer (score 0):

Use Skype to make the call, [CallGraph](http://callgraph.biz/free-skype-recorder) to record the call

Comment: Is Skype untraceable?

Comment: It is encrypted, i don't know if they have been forced to introduce a backdoor to their software. There as been an argument between the american government anti terror forces, that this should be done. If there is this backdoor, use any VoIP software like Teamspeak or whatever over an VPN-Tunnel. That maybe tracable, but as long as the systems are not compromised... Nobody in the next years will be able to decode it. Together with the thor network... It is even almost untracable.

Comment: There's a big difference between _tracing_ a call or message to its source, and _intercepting_ it. Encryption stops the latter -- no one except the sender and recipient can read/hear it -- but it does not prevent the recipient, or an outsider, from finding the message's source. (Also, @Darokthar, it's "Tor".)

Comment: @ grawity I was not sure if it was Thor or Tor and was too lazy to google *g* Sorry for that. I know, that a VPN Tunnel and Teamspeak are traceable maybe i should have written IS instead of "That maybe traceable..." But if you use Tor additionally to an VPN-Tunnel this will be hard to trace.

Comment: @Darokthar your reply format will not result in grawity getting the reply notification, please have a look at [How does comment @reply work](http://meta.superuser.com/q/2081/4377)

Comment: Skype would be hard to trace. Although I recommend a peer blocker, a proxy and if resources were abundant, a VPN service.